# Enable antialiasing of text in all Swing-application components

Tags: java, swing

There is a problem with smoothing component;s content. The text on the button does not become smooth.

```
JButton button = new JButton("Button"){
  public void PaintComponent(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    //g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    super.paintComponent(g2d);
    g2d.dispose();
  }
};
```

I don't want to create a separate class and override the `paintComponent()`, causing the methods `g2d.setRenderingHint(...)` and `g2d.drawString("Button")`.

The problem is that for all Swing components of my application, must turn on anti-aliasing of text in them. Impossible override the methods of `paintComponent()` all items by hand.

Naturally, the inclusion of text anti-aliasing in the system settings does nothing to solve the problem.

Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo. Change the `P` to `p` for the `paintComponent(...)` method.

In general, when overriding a method you should use `@Override` before the method:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    ...
}
```

The `@Override` annotation will generate a compile error if you override the method incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks for Your answer ,asked, but the problem remained. Rewrote method so, but the inscription non-smooth;